# Fluent configurator/builder and IoC container

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control

I'm about to create a fluent configurator/builder for my class when I realized I don't know how to use it together with my IoC container.

Let's say I create a class and a builder like this.

```
class MyClass
{
    private ILog _log;

    // here I want the ILog object from my container and configParameter1 from my builder.
    internal MyClass(ILog log, int configParameter1)
    {

    }
}

class MyClassBuilder
{
    private int _param1;
    private MyClassBuilder () {}

    public static MyClassBuilder Begin()
    {
        return new MyClassBuilder();
    }

    public MyClassBuilder SetParameter1(int param1)
    {
        _param1 = param1;
        return this;
    }

    public MyClass Build()
    {
        // Here I want to inject a ILog object from my container
        return new MyClass(?!?, _param1);
    }
}
```

The class MyClass depend on both types registered in my container and parameters from may builder. What is the best way to solve this? Should MyClassBuilder depend on ILog? If so I'm not able to use a static Begin method in the builder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could inject a factory into your `MyClassBuilder`:

```
class LogFactory
{

    public ILog CreateLogger(){

    }
}
```

Then you can ask this `LogFactory` to be injected into your builder:

```
class MyClassBuilder
{
    public MyClassBuilder(LogFactory factory)
    {
        _factory = factory;
    }

    // ... Builder methods

    public MyClass Build()
    {
        return new MyClass(_factory.CreateLogger(), _param1);
    }
}
```

Comment: This is almost the same thing as letting MyClassBuilder depend on ILog. Both ways you need to inject something from the container and by doing that you are not able to use a static Begin().

Comment: That's also a possibility. You have a dependency to be resolved at runtime, so at some point you will to have it injected somewhere. Since you have moved that dependency to `MyClassBuilder`, you should also inject `MyClassBuilder`, otherwise you're employing Service Locator, which is an anti-pattern.

Answer (score 0):

can't you just inject ILog to MyClass or use smth like this:

```
private static ILog logger = LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(MyClass));
```